# Website files being cached on a Debian webserver running PHP 5.5.28

Tags: linux, debian, php, cache

When I make small changes to my website and upload them it usually takes a few minutes for those changes to be reflected live. It only started happening after I installed a new debian system through Google Compute Engine.

I have ruled out that I have code that is caching it, but is it possible that PHP 5.5.28 or Debian could be caching files? I’ve also checked to make sure it is not the browser and have used the chrome option to not cache files in the developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using PHP 5.5.28, and in my experience anyone jumping from PHP 5.3 or 5.4 to PHP 5.5 needs to be aware about the new built-in [OPcache (Operations Cache)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php) being enabled by default.

If you have ever used [APC (Alternative PHP Cache)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), the new built-in OPcache works pretty much the same and is nice for production purposes for complex code, but it being enabled by default can bite you if you are used to uploading files and have changes showing up immediately.

[This site does a good job](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/enable-php-5-5-opcache-ubuntu-14-04/) of explaining what OPcache is and how to tweak it. But if you don’t need OPcache yet, just open up your PHP ini file like this; I prefer to use [`nano`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) but feel free to use whatever text editor you like using:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Look for the line that reads:

```
opcache.enable=1
```

And just disable it by changing that line to:

```
;opcache.enable=0
```

Restart Apache and now PHP 5.5 won’t use OPcache. And honestly enabling a cache like that should be a call of the system administrator and their knowledge of how the code works and how the server reacts

If your PHP-based site is lightweight enough, OPcache might just be overkill, really not needed and might even get in the way.

But if you need OPcache but also need to update PHP files regularly maybe [tweaking the OPcache configuration values would help](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php). The default settings are something like this:

```
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

The key thing I see in that config that might trip up an expected update is [`opcache.revalidate_freq`](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq):

> How often to check script timestamps for updates, in seconds. 0 will
>   result in OPcache checking for updates on every request.

The default of 60 seconds is fine, but it seems to me that lowering the `opcache.revalidate_freq` to something like 5 seconds might be a nicer way of having the benefit of OPcache enabled, but still having a reasonable update check window so you don’t get tripped up by simple file updates.